# How to add a title to a datatables table?

Tags: datatables-1.10

I have a DataTables table, and I want to put a title on the table to the left of the search box, like this:

[image]

I've tried a few things from Goog and [the docs](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-11-07), such as floating an element above the table and caption, which don't look great and look even worse when styling is applied.

Looking through the elements, there seems to be a space already there and available for a title, but I don't know how to access it:

[image]

How can I add a title to a DataTables table so it's inline and to the left of the search area.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to modify the structure of the [dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom).

You can add for example a div with a class name in your table config

```
'dom' : '<"my-class">'
```

and once the table is fully created you can insert some text using jquery

```
'initComplete' : function( settings, json ) {
     $('.my-class').html('Datatable title');
}
```

I hope I was helpful